# necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix A to be Unitary

Tags: linear-algebra

I managed to prove that if $A$ is unitary than for any base orthonormal base $\{u_i\}$: $\{A^*u_i\}$ is also orthonormal base.

I need some help proving that it's an if and only if,  and not only if. I only managed to say that $A$ is invertible since $\{A^*u_i\}$ is also a base.

**Edit**: I'm using the definition "$A$ is unitary if $AA^*=A^*A=I$.

Comment: There are many equivalent properties to define unitary. What is the definition of "unitary" that you are using?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I edited the question to add this

Comment: ... and obliterated the other fixes... re-added now.

Comment: thanks for the edit, I really need to learn latex...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT.** Note that
$$
AA^*u_i = \sum_{j=1}^n \langle AA^*u_i,u_j\rangle u_j
= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle A^*u_i,A^*u_j\rangle u_j.
$$